# Vue JS : Method Style Getter (to filtering) AND reactivity to state change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, state, getter

I worked on a simple schedule application and i use Vuex as a state manager.

I want a way to filter the task state, to only return specific date and category tasks (Method Style Getter ig?) but i also want the component which get these tasks (via Method Style Getter) to react (so rerender) every time the task state change.

What is the most effective way to get there?

---

Access the tasks

```js
export default {
  name: "TasksContainer",
  methods: {
    logSomething() {
      console.log("new task (good)");
    },
  },
  components: {
    Task,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["weekCourseTasks", "courseTasks", "nowMoment"]),
  },
};
```

Update tasks

```
export default {
  name: "AddTask",
  data() {
    return {
      taskName: "",
      taskDetail: "",
      taskCourse: "",
      taskDate: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addTask"]),
    postForm() {
      this.addTask({
        taskName: this.taskName,
        taskDetail: this.taskDetail,
        taskCourse: this.taskCourse,
        taskDate: this.taskDate,
      });

      this.$emit("new-task");
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to have tasks, that you can filter based on the date and other categories.
Vuex allows for such getter methods.

The following code block allows you to write getters based on parameters.

```
getters: {
// ...
  getTaskByDate: (state) => (date) => {
    return state.tasks.find(task => task.date === date)
  }
}
```

In order to see them:

```
store.getters.getTaskByDate(xyz);
```

This should allow you to filter your state and make the component responsive.

A full documentation can be found [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) under the part "Method-Style Access"

Additionally, be sure to perform your updates according to the guidelines to preserve reactivity.

> Since a Vuex store's state is made reactive by Vue, when we mutate the
> state, Vue components observing the state will update automatically.
> This also means Vuex mutations are subject to the same reactivity
> caveats when working with plain Vue:
>
> Prefer initializing your store's initial state with all desired fields
> upfront.
>
> When adding new properties to an Object, you should either:
>
> Use Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123), or
>
> Replace that Object with a fresh one. For example, using the object
> spread syntax we can write it like this:

```
state.obj = { ...state.obj, newProp: 123 }
```

(From the Vuex [mutations documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html))

Comment: thank you for your answer, however I have already tried this technique however I have the impression that using a method-style getter  removes the reactivity on the state in the component.

at least that's what happens in my project.

Comment: Could you give a short reproducible example of your problem? How do you access your tasks in your Vue component and how do you update your tasks?

Comment: It does matter how you update your task data to preserve reactivity. Your updates should always happen in a mutation. Additionally, you should not add new properties to an Object but replace the object itself. (Or use Vue.set())